# Beautifulsoup not finding all class elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all tables with a class of "stats_table". However it is only pulling 2 tables. Yet when I print the actual soup it and search the document (manually) I can find 9 tables.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# function to get hitting stats
def get_hitting_stats(team, soup):
    # get tables
    tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="stats_table")
    print(tables)
    
# function to process game
def process_game(gamelink, headers):
    # get boxscore page 
    req = requests.get(gamelink, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
  
    home_hitting = get_hitting_stats("home", soup)
    away_hitting = get_hitting_stats("away", soup)
   
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
}
process_game("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CLE/CLE202208151.shtml", headers)
```

Originally I thought that the other tables might be retrieved from a different request but it doesn't make sense that when I look at the soup returned I can find more than the two tables my code does. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `def process_game(gamelink headers):` You seem to be missing a comma here, are you sure this is copy/pasted *directly* from what you're working with? This should throw some semblance of an error when run.

Comment: sorry, the actual code has more complexity that I removed as it was unrelated. I will edit this.

Comment: Are any of those _missing_ tables actually within comment blocks?

Comment: All those tables are being hydrated into page by js after the original html (which reaquests can see) is loaded. Check those api endpoints in network tab, and scrape those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is within the comments. You need to pull it out.

Also, you never return anything in the functions. Is that what you want to do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

# function to get hitting stats
def get_hitting_stats(home_away, soup):
    # get tables
    idx = {'home':1, 'away':0}
    hitting = soup.find_all('table', {'id':re.compile('.*batting.*')})
    
    html = str(hitting[idx[home_away]])
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
    print(df)
    return df
    
# function to process game
def process_game(gamelink, headers):
    # get boxscore page 
    html = requests.get(gamelink, headers).text
    html = html.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    home_hitting = get_hitting_stats("home", soup)
    away_hitting = get_hitting_stats("away", soup)
   
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
}
process_game("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CLE/CLE202208151.shtml", headers)
```

**Output:**

```
              Batting    AB    R    H  RBI  ...  acLI  RE24    PO    A  Details
0      Steven Kwan LF   4.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...  1.76   0.1   0.0  0.0      NaN
1     Amed Rosario SS   4.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  ...  1.49  -1.5   0.0  1.0      NaN
2     Jose Ramirez 3B   4.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  ...  1.72   0.5   0.0  0.0      NaN
3   Andres Gimenez 2B   4.0  1.0  3.0  3.0  ...  1.84   3.6   0.0  4.0    HR,2B
4   Oscar Gonzalez RF   4.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  ...  1.38   0.3   3.0  0.0       2B
5      Owen Miller 1B   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  1.71  -1.1   5.0  3.0      GDP
6      Nolan Jones DH   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  1.77  -1.6   NaN  NaN      NaN
7     Austin Hedges C   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  1.77  -1.2  13.0  0.0      NaN
8      Myles Straw CF   3.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  ...  1.09   1.0   3.0  0.0     2·SB
9                 NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
10     Aaron Civale P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   1.0  0.0      NaN
11  James Karinchak P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  0.0      NaN
12   Trevor Stephan P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   2.0  0.0      NaN
13   Emmanuel Clase P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  0.0      NaN
14        Team Totals  33.0  4.0  9.0  4.0  ...  1.59   0.3  27.0  8.0      NaN

[15 rows x 24 columns]
                 Batting    AB    R    H  RBI  ...  acLI  RE24    PO    A  Details
0        Riley Greene CF   4.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.1   3.0  0.0      NaN
1        Victor Reyes RF   3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   1.0  0.0       SB
2         Javier Baez SS   4.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.2   2.0  3.0       2B
3       Harold Castro 1B   4.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  ...   0.0  -0.7   7.0  0.0      NaN
4      Miguel Cabrera DH   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.8   NaN  NaN      NaN
5   Jeimer Candelario 3B   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.5   1.0  1.0      NaN
6           Eric Haase C   2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.3   6.0  1.0      NaN
7     Jonathan Schoop 2B   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.5   1.0  2.0      NaN
8         Akil Baddoo LF   3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0  -0.5   3.0  0.0      NaN
9                    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN      NaN
10      Drew Hutchison P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  0.0      NaN
11           Will Vest P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  1.0      NaN
12       Andrew Chafin P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  0.0      NaN
13        Wily Peralta P   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   0.0  0.0      NaN
14           Team Totals  30.0  1.0  3.0  1.0  ...   0.0  -3.2  24.0  8.0      NaN

[15 rows x 24 columns]
```